# How to pass parameter to a java function in JSP scriptlet?

Tags: scriptlet

I want to pass the value of assembler.area.id, sent by controller to the java function getIsAreaWaitTimeActiveByAreaId(), inside scriptlet. I am not sure how to do so. getIsAreaWaitTimeActiveByAreaId() takes in Long.

```
<c:set var="isWaitTimeActive" value="${assembler.area.id}" scope="page"/>
<%@page import="com.ihc.wtrack.service.impl.ReportServiceImpl"%>
   <%
      ReportServiceImpl reportController = new ReportServiceImpl();
      boolean isActive = reportController.getIsAreaWaitTimeActiveByAreaId(isWaitTimeActive);
    %>
```

Thanks.